# Como utilizar Consumer numa variável (Java 8)

Tags: java-8, programação-funcional

Criei uma estrutura de dados própria para um game Text Adventure, e nela cada objeto Action tem um Consumer.
 O próximo passo seria sempre que alguém digitasse uma palavra, percorrer a estrutura e se encontrar uma Action que contém a String digitada num vetor, executar esse Consumer (valor padrão 1).
 Mas não consigo criar um código do tipo "Action.function(1)". para contornar isso, tive que usar o forEach, assim:

```
public static void exec(Consumer<Integer> c, int i) {
    ArrayList<Integer> is = new ArrayList<>();
    is.add(i);
    is.forEach(c);
}
```

O que me parece uma gambiarra. Alguém conhece uma forma mais correta de usar meu Consumer dentro do código, sem ter que criar uma nova ArrayList (ou whatever) só pra isso?
 Se necessário, aqui parte do código do meu objeto Action:
    public class Action implements Iterable {

```
String id;
String[] functionNames;
Consumer<Integer> function;
Action next;

public Action(String id, Consumer<Integer> function, String... names) {
    this.id = id;
    this.function = function;
    this.functionNames = names;
    this.next = null;
}

@Override
public Iterator iterator() {
    return new ActionIterator(this);
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Seria [`c.accept(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-)?

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!
Sou novo no Java 8, ainda estou aprendendo a usar esses novos métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Java 8, uma [**Interface Funcional**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) é qualquer `interface` que possui exatamente 1 método abstrato (ela pode *também* ter métodos padrão, ou declarar abstratos métodos de `Object`, mas precisa ter 1 método abstrato além disso). [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) é uma interface funcional, cujo método é [`void accept(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-).

É esse portanto o método que será chamado pelo `ArrayList.forEach`, de modo que para se obter um efeito equivalente ao seu exemplo é só usar:

```
c.accept(i);
```